# Trouble with array malloc&free

Tags: c, arrays

I have a problem with an array.

It shows an error: *"Unhandled exception at 0x5A90B2CE (msvcr120d.dll) in lab2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."* when I want to free the memory of integer - age (free(my_array[i][1]);).

Can anyone help me with that? I don't know what should I do...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



void * my_array[5][3];
int i, j, age;
const int max = 50;

void memory_loc();
void getting_values();
void showing_values();
void memory_free();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    memory_loc();
    getting_values();
    showing_values();
    memory_free();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

void memory_loc()
{
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        my_array[i][0] = malloc(sizeof(char)* 50);
        my_array[i][1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
        my_array[i][2] = malloc(sizeof(char)* 50);
    }
}

void getting_values()
{
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d\n", i);
        printf("Name and surname: \n");
        fgets((char*)my_array[i][0], max, stdin);

        printf("Age: \n");
        scanf("%d", &age);
        (int*)my_array[i][1] = age;
        getc(stdin);

        printf("Location: \n");
        fgets((char*)my_array[i][2], max, stdin);
    }
}

void showing_values()
{
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("\nName and surname: %s", my_array[i][0]);
        printf("\nAge: %d", my_array[i][1]);
        printf("\nLocation: %s", my_array[i][2]);
    }
}

void memory_free()
{
    for (i = 4; i>=0; i--)
    {
        free(my_array[i][2]);
        free(my_array[i][1]);
        free(my_array[i][0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: check you compiler's warning messages, you have couple of mistakes.

Comment: You don't have to `free` in reverse order, so you can just use the same `for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)` at the end

Comment: Why that `void*` multidimensional array? Why not a `struct{int age; char *name; char *location;};`? BTW, if you have a set of free length strings to store, a typical pattern is to use a `struct S{int age; size_t name_length; size_t location_length; char name_location[];};` and `malloc`-ing `sizeof(S) + name_length + location_length` and appending the strings to the contents of the struct; you can access them through the array of unspecified length at the end of the struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've altered what `my_array[i][1]` points to here:

```
(int*)my_array[i][1] = age;
```

Which causes the exception in `free`, since you're trying to free memory that you haven't allocated.

You probably meant to write:

```
*(int*)(my_array[i][1]) = age;
```

---

As someone commented, you could've caught this if you had read the compiler warnings. You should've gotten a warning saying that you're implictly casting an integer to a pointer, or something of that nature.

Comment: `my_array[i][1]` isn't an `int`, it's a `void*`. Therefore, `(int)(my_array[i][1]) = age;` is not a correct way to assign the value of `age` to the memory location that `my_array[i][1]` points to. Use `*(int*)(my_array[i][1]) = age;` like I wrote in my answer. Likewise, when you want to get the value, use `*(int*)(my_array[i][1])`.

Comment: Yes, I wrote `*(int*)(my_array[i][1]) = age;` like you wrote, I just had some problems with posting it correctly here. But now I have problem with getting the values, because in my showing_values function it shows me the memory location, not the values of age.